# pandas dropna not working as expected on finding mean

Tags: python, pandas

When I run the code below I get the error:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
    import pyarrow 
    import pandas
    import pyarrow.parquet as pq

    df = pq.read_table("file.parquet").to_pandas()
    df = df.iloc[1:,:]
    df = df.dropna (how="any", inplace = True) # modifies it in place, creates new dataset without NAN

    average_age = df["_c2"].mean()
    print average_age
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
         _c0     _c1  _c2    
    0  RecId   Class  Age   
    1      1      1st   29   
    2      2      1st   NA   
    3      3      1st   30
```

If I print the df after calling the dropna method, I get 'None'.

Shouldn't it be creating a new dataframe without the 'NA' in it, which would then allow me to get the average age without throwing an error?

Comment: Have your tried `inplace=false`

Comment: Yes, but the NA doesn't get removed if it's inplace = False

Comment: It looks like "RecId", "Class", "Age" are the column names but appear in the value in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

As per OP’s comment, the NA is a string rather than NaN. So `dropna()` is no good here. One of many possible options for filtering out the string value ‘NA’ is:

```
df = df[df["_c2"] != "NA"]
```

A better option to catch inexact matches (e.g. with trailing spaces) as suggested by @DJK in the comments:

```
df = df[~df["_c2"].str.contains('NA')]
```

This one should remove any strings rather than only ‘NA’:

```
df = df[df[“_c2”].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
```

Comment: with both of those options I got the error I had before implementing dropna: TypeError('Could not convert %s to numeric' % str(x))

Comment: Is it possible that your DataFrame contains the string ‘NA’ rather than NAN?

Comment: yes it does, exactly. I thought dropna would remove anything that wasn't a number though.

Comment: My understanding is that it only drops the special value NaN, not strings. I will edit the answer to something that works for strings.

Comment: maybe `df[~df["_c2"].str.contains('NA')]`, could be a space problem on an exact match

Comment: Thanks - definitely better than my exact match solution, will update answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, also if you the NA in your df is  NaN (np.nan), this will not affect your getting the mean of the column, only if your NA is 'NA', which is string

```
(df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors ='coerce',axis=1)).describe()
Out[9]: 
       _c0  _c1        _c2
count  3.0  0.0   2.000000
mean   2.0  NaN  29.500000
std    1.0  NaN   0.707107
min    1.0  NaN  29.000000
25%    1.5  NaN  29.250000
50%    2.0  NaN  29.500000
75%    2.5  NaN  29.750000
max    3.0  NaN  30.000000
```

More info

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors ='coerce',axis=1)# all object change to NaN and will not affect getting mean
Out[10]: 
   _c0  _c1   _c2
0  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  1.0  NaN  29.0
2  2.0  NaN   NaN
3  3.0  NaN  30.0
```